Getting undefined when assigning string to enum in typescript
We are trying to assign a text to an enum variable but getting undefined
  enum Color {
    Green = "GRN",
    Red = "RD"
  }

  let text: string = "GRN";
  let test: Color = Color[text as keyof typeof Color];
  
  console.log(test);

This returns to undefined
Any help would be appreciated.

What do you expect to see? String enums in TS don't get reverse mappings, so while Color.Green === "GRN", there is no Color.GRN defined. Are you trying to do some kind of lookup? Do you expect "Green" to come out? Please [edit] to clarify what your expected behavior is, because right now this is all behaving as intended.

The issue occured because you are trying to access the enum value using a string that is not matched directly with the enum keys.
In TypeScript, enums can be accessed by their keys, but when you use the string representation of the value (like "GRN"), it won't map correctly.
You can create a function that returns the enum key when given its corresponding value:
enum Color {
    Green = "GRN",
    Red = "RD"
}

let text: string = "GRN";

// Function to get Enum key from its value
function getEnumKeyByValue(enumObj: any, value: string) {
    return Object.keys(enumObj).find(key => enumObj[key as keyof typeof Color] === value);
}

let testKey: keyof typeof Color | undefined = getEnumKeyByValue(Color, text);

console.log(testKey); // Output will be 'Green'
console.log(testKey ? Color[testKey] : undefined); // Output will be 'GRN'

